# array displays as empty after using .push() via loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

i can't show any object in my display. Please see if my current code is properly structured:

```
var users = []; 

function execCrossDomainRequestIdFromUri() {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/siteusers?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
                var allResults = jsonObject.d.results;
                users ;
                for (var i = 0; i < allResults.length; i++) {
                    users.push({ name: allResults[i].Title, id: allResults[i].Id });
                }
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
}
console.log(users)
```

[image: Array in conse.log()]

Comment: `i` stands it evaluated right after you log.

Comment: You need to do `console.log(users)` inside the `success` function. Because its an `async` request, your `console.log()` will get executed even before the request is completed. Hence, it will always be empty.

Comment: Yes but is any way to get object outside the success?